# Get current category ID of the active page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

Looking to pull the category ID of a specific page in WordPress that is listing all posts using that specific category.  Tried the below but not working.  I am able to get the category name using `single_term_title`.

```
$category = single_term_title("", false);
$catid = get_cat_ID( $category );
```

`$category` is displaying "Entertainment" for example. But I also need the ID of "Entertainment".  How would I go about this?

Comment: Is it a normal category page or custom page template?

Comment: it is a custom taxonomy - trying to use this on a file named `taxonomy-event-categories-entertainment.php`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can try using [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category):

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
```

Comment: $category[0]->cat_ID to be accurate.

Comment: This method actually checks the first category of the first post on the page. If there are no posts or if the first post has multiple categories, this will fail or return incorrect info.

Comment: I agree with @JordanEldredge, this will return incorrect info.

Comment: This will return the first category of the first post of the page.

Comment: It will also fail if the viewed page is a subcategory. Check for the output of the `$categories` array.

Comment: My test site contain no other category and the post doesn't select it so this return nothing.

Answer (score 212):

If it is a category page,you can get id of current category by:

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
```

If you want to get category id of any particular category on any page, try using :

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Better than the above answer if you are creating a generic Category template as you only get the Category the page will display as opposed to the multi-Category array from the above.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me. I was having problem getting the ID and worked lovely for me. Saved hours :)

Comment: Need to replace the correct answer! The answer marked correct, misled me.

Comment: This answer has some unnecessary code. The first line of code gets the full category data in get_category function by using one parameter - CATEGORY ID (because this is what get_query_var( 'cat' ) returns). The second line of code actually retrieves the id from the data. This means that the get_category function is completely unused here and if someone wants only the id, then just get_query_var( 'cat' ) should be used!

Comment: @RamMeharDeswal is it possible to use this method to get the child category ?

Comment: Good code mate, it works with pagination!!! get_the_category() gave a whole array in pagination instead of the current category.
someone should changed the correct answer to this one!

Comment: My test site contain uncategorized my post don't select any category and `get_query_var( 'cat' )` return empty.

Answer (score 41):

The oldest but fastest way you can use is:

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
```

Comment: this seems perfect. are there drawbacks to this over Ram Mehar Deswal's answer?

Comment: This is actually the working solution, it will display the category of the viewed page.

Comment: @dewd look for Bartosz Górski's comment in Ram Mehar Deswal's answer. He is completly right and this answer right here does all you need.

Comment: @honk31 thx for pointing me to that you good SO citizen you! :)

Comment: get_query_var( 'cat' ) is falsy for me

Answer (score 24):

I use the get_queried_object function to get the current category on a category.php template page.

```
$current_category = get_queried_object();
```

Jordan Eldredge is right, get_the_category is not suitable here.

Comment: Nice, never seen this one before.

Comment: If the result is not the expected one, invoke `wp_reset_query();` to restore the default WP_Query instance.

Comment: This is actually the most useful Wordpress function I have ever found. It's usable everywhere: pages, articles, categories etc.

Answer (score 4):

I think some of the above may work but using the get_the_category function seems tricky and may give unexpected results.

I think the most direct and simple way to access the cat ID in a category page is:

```
$wp_query->query_vars['cat']
```

Cheers

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you need the category ID, you would get it via [get_query_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/), that is capable of retrieving all publicly queryble variables.

```
$category_id = get_query_var('cat');
```

here is an example to get the category name

```
$category_name = get_query_var('category_name');
```

and of course the all mighty [get_queried_object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/)

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
```

that is returning the complete taxonomy term object (when used on a taxonomy-archive page..)

Answer (score 2):

I tested all these answers and this is the only one which works on all archive  page types including posts page.

```
$category_id = get_the_category( get_the_ID());
$cat_id      = get_category($category_id[0]->term_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this question whilst looking for exactly what you asked. Unfortunately you have accepted an incorrect answer. For the sake of other people who are trying to achieve what we were trying to achieve, I thought I'd post the correct answer.

```
$cur_cat = get_cat_ID( single_cat_title("",false) );
```

As you said `single_term_title("", false);` was correctly returning the category title, I'm not sure why you would have had troubles with your code; but the above code works flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative -

```
 $catID = the_category_ID($echo=false);
```

EDIT: Above function is deprecated please use `get_the_category()`

Comment: FYI: This function has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for breadcrums in the category template page:

```
$cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$thiscat_id = $cat_obj->term_id;
$thiscat = get_category($thiscat_id);
$parentcat = get_category($thiscat->parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach($cats as $cat){
/*check for category having parent or not except category id=1 which is wordpress default category (Uncategorized)*/
  if($cat->parent != '0' && $cat->term_id != 1){
    echo '<h2 class="link"><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id ).'">'.$cat->name.'</a></h2>';
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried above for solutions to find cat ID of a post, but nothing worked, used the following instead:

```
$obj = get_queried_object();
$c_id = wp_get_post_categories($obj->ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an efficient method to get category meta data, along with HTML if you want to print it out on the front-end:

```php
    <?php
    
    function custom_get_categories() {
      $categories = get_the_category();
      $uncategorised_id = get_cat_ID('Uncategorized');
      $custom_category_link = '';
    
      foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if($category->category_parent == $uncategorised_id || $category->cat_ID == $uncategorised_id) {
          continue;
        }
        
        $custom_category_link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID); ?>
    
        <a href ="<?php echo $custom_category_link ?>"> 
    <?php echo "\n\nCategory ID: " . $category->cat_ID . "\nCategory Name" . $category->name;  ?> </a>
    
        <?php
      }``
    }
    
     ?>
```

Comment: Hello Hemant Adhikari. Please separate the text from the code in your post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).