# highlighting category in archive - Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

My Wordpress index/home page has all my posts on it. I have the following code which lists the categories on my page including an "all" since all the posts are listed on this page.

HTML

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'show_option_all' => 'All posts'
    );
?>

<h3><?php wp_list_categories($args); ?></h3>
```

CSS - highlights 'all' in the list since its the page you're on.

```
li.cat-item-all a{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Each category link opens up the archive page with the posts tagged with that category.

I want this list to act as a navigation, with the category chosen 'highlighted' when you select it. Similar to how home would be highlighted when you're on the home page. But all the links link to the archive page so I'm not sure the coding

EDIT - output on home page

[image]

I want this to appear on my archives page, but with the category that they selected highlighted instead of 'ALL'

Comment: Post the HTML output of both. A demo of the page would be nice.

Comment: unfortunately it's on local-host so I can't demo the page, I'll post the output in my question as an edit

Comment: Can you add HTML output instead of image of the output?

Comment: without markup it's quite impossible to give an answer, but you could use [CSS :not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) to exclude highlighting on 'all items'

Comment: There is to much Wordpress involved to create a jsFiddle. I'm basically wondering if there is code that I can put on my archive page which will detect which category they are on and highlight it. Or something similar.

Comment: Try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829632/get-current-category-id-of-the-active-page

Comment: sounds like it's on the right track,i'll have to figure out how to use it

Comment: it should be something like `.archive .categories li:not(.cat-item-all)`, let me know if my guess is correct

Comment: @maioman He wants to highlight only the current category. Your code will highlight all the other categories right?

Comment: I want to highlight just the category that the page is displaying, but I want all the other categories still listed. The current archive code just puts the title of the category that the page is displaying, but thats it

Comment: Upload your localhost files to a server, I can find you a easy solution.

Comment: @ManojKumar I thought he wanted to exclude highlight on ALL

Comment: Wordpress adds `current-cat` class to the current category `<li>`, but it does not add it to the "All posts" `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [wp_list_categories()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) by default the current category has a class of `current-cat`. So, your CSS would be:

```
.current-cat {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

To get the 'all' "category" to highlight, you'd need to reference the body classes (so you know where you are, and can highlight the .cat-item-all link only when you're on the all-posts page). In my testing, that "All posts" link actually goes to my site home page, which has body classes of:

```
<body class="home page page-id-3745 page-template page-template-tmpl-home page-template-tmpl-home-php">
```

so the CSS to highlight .cat-all-items would be

```
.home .cat-all-items {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

On your site the all-posts page might be your main blog page so the body classes would be slightly different - be sure to check.